# Random ECONREFUSED from webdriver / chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

We have written a bunch of e2e tests for an angular4 app, that we are developing. The problem is that I am getting random ECONNREFUSED message from webdriver / chrome, when running automated tests with protractor.

```
- Failed: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:54657
```

Protractor is running with shardedtestfiles turned on, and running with 12 browsers in parallel, in order to speed up testing.

I can't pinpoint an exact pattern to the errors that we get, so I am a bit lost here.. Below is a copy of the protractor config file, that we are using.

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

//*global jasmine */

"use strict";
var SpecReporter = require("jasmine-spec-reporter").SpecReporter;
var timeoutSettings = require('./dist/out-tsc/e2e/protractor.config').timeoutSettings

exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 99999,
    suites: {
        spec: [
        "./dist/out-tsc/e2e/spec/**/*spec.js"
        ]
    },

    capabilities: {
      browserName: "chrome",
      maxInstances: 12,
      chromeOptions: {
        args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-infobars", "--start-maximized", "--lang=DA-dk"],
        prefs: {
            download: {
            promt_for_download: false,
            default_directory: "spec/downloads" // To Do: Make sure this dir is correct!
            },
            "profile.password_manager_enabled": false,
            credentials_enable_service: false,
            password_manager_enabled: false
        }
      }
    },

    directConnect: true,
    framework: "jasmine",
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
        print: function () {}
    },

    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    beforeLaunch: function () {
        require("ts-node").register({
            project: "./e2e/tsconfig.json"
        });
    },

    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeoutSettings.implicitWaitNormal);
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));

        var trx = require("jasmine-trx-reporter");
        return browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
            var browserName = caps.get("browserName").toUpperCase();

            var jasmineTrxConfig = {
                reportName: "Protractor Test Results",
                folder: "reports",
                outputFile: "",
                browser: "GANDALF_" + browserName,
                groupSuitesIntoSingleFile: false,
                takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: false
            };
            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new trx(jasmineTrxConfig));
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is actually a problem in the version of selenium webdriver, that is pulled in, when using protractor

There is a discussion in an issue with protractor on github 
https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4792